# How to create a composite key with all but on columns nullable?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-administration

I have an entity which does not have any natural primary key. A unique row is identified by three columns, any one of which can have a unique value and other columns will be null.

For the sake of an imaginary example, here is my entity:

```
--------
Product
--------
Shelf
Order
Customer
Category
--------
```

Only one of Shelf or Order of Customer or Category column will have a filled value, probably with an ID (will not be an FK from another table).

How do I design a table for it? I strictly need to identify unique rows solely on these columns. I am using Oracle DB if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably can't.

> A unique row is identified by three columns, any one of which can have a unique value and **other columns will be null**.

That's a *showstopper*. Although you CAN create unique composite key on these 4 columns, everything will be OK until you try to insert another row which already contains that combination.

For example:

```
SQL> create table product
  2    (shelf     number,
  3     c_order   number,
  4     customer  number,
  5     category  number,
  6     --
  7     constraint uk_product unique (shelf, c_order, customer, category)
  8    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into product (shelf, c_order, customer, category) values (1, null, null, null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product (shelf, c_order, customer, category) values (2, null, 8, null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product (shelf, c_order, customer, category) values (1, null, 4, null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product (shelf, c_order, customer, category) values (1, null, null, null);
insert into product (shelf, c_order, customer, category) values (1, null, null, null)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UK_PRODUCT) violated
```

This row failed because such a combination already exists (it was the very first row I inserted).

If that's OK with you - I mean, you really do expect something like this to happen - then it'll work. If not, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a unique constraint (not a primary key). Unique constraints permit their column members to be NULL-able, treating NULL as a distinct value. This is useful particularly when the nullable column is some kind of indicator of state/currency (e.g. a NULL `end_date` could signify a currently active row in an historical type-2 table, and the constraint enforces that no entity have more than one NULL `end_date`, that is, more than one active/current row). If you wanted to create a constraint, you'd say:

```
constraint uq_product unique ("Shelf","Order","Customer","Category")
```

However, your particular situation doesn't lend itself to this. Honestly I can't imagine why you would have a design in which *shelf*, *order*, *customer* and *category* would all be nullable, nor why you would have an identifying value in only one of these, nor why the column with an identifying value would shift around. None of those, except for perhaps *order*, sound like an identifying column, nor the combination of them together. It makes no sense to have only one of these have a value while the others do not. This is a definite design flaw that should corrected by redesigning your table(s).

Either correct your design so that you do have a proper identifying key, or simply don't attempt to create a key of any kind. Tables don't have to have constraints on them. But I suspect you probably should fix the design so that you will.

Comment: That example was just for the sake of it. There is no meaning behind choosing those names. Nevertheless, i understand your concern about redesigning but unfortunately i don't have much control over the situation.